# video advertisement networks working with video.js

Tags: video.js, ads

Recnetly, I have seen a video.js plugin (https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-ads) that provides common functionality needed by video advertisement libraries.

Since I'm pretty new to this area, not sure what kind kinds of video networks can be used here, in addition to Google Video Adsense.

Could you list all possible (and well-known) video networks that can be used with this library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

videojs-contrib-ads is just a framework for ad support, you do need an additional plugin that builds off that to interact with the ad server and act on the response. Google's  [IMA plugin](https://github.com/googleads/videojs-ima) is an example of that, and should work not only with DFP but with other VAST-compliant ad servers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already knew that videojs-contrib-ads is just a framework for ad support. I want to know a list of VAST-compliant ad servers.